# Ivy resolve multi module apache maven POM.xml

Tags: ant, ivy, pom.xml, multi-project

If i have multi module project written in maven pom.xml in this architechture

```
pom.xml -main
---module1/pom.xml 
---module2/pom.xml
```

---

and main pom.xml looks like this

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>My group id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
```

and each module have it own dependencies.

How can i resolve, and retrieve all these dependencies via IVY to build my project using Ivy+Ant.
Problem is only in multi module project, because when there is only 1 jar/war produced by project there are no probelm to resolve and retrieve dependencies with ivy+ant

But when during runtime there are created ejb.jar ejb.client.jar and 2-4 other  modules , ivy just can't dont resolve

Comment: If you have already a maven build why would you like to do it with Ivy ?

Comment: An example where this is needed is Unitils (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.unitils/unitils/3.3 ) Let's say I want the whole thing, I'd expect that I only have to add this dependency. Inside the pom.xml there is the module definition containing all available modules. But Ivy does not fetch these.

Comment: another use-case: use an legacy multi-module maven build as a submodule of a sbt build (and therefore ivy implicitly).

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure of what you are doing (as far as I know retrieve does not have a file="" attribute). Your example is hard to understand.
I'd suggest reading the documentation for ivy and multiple projects:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/multiproject.html

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/conf.html